# PDF Box - Getting error while adding title

Tags: java, pdfbox

I Tried adding title , but am getting error for `pdPageContentStream.drawString();` 
Error: " drawString(java.lang.String)' is deprecated "

```
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        // PDRectangle.LETTER and others are also possible
        PDRectangle rect = page.getMediaBox();
        document.addPage(page);

        try {
            // Create a Content Stream
            PDPageContentStream pdPageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
            pdPageContentStream.beginText();
            pdPageContentStream.drawString();
            pdPageContentStream.endText();
            // Creating an PDImageXObject object
            PDImageXObject pdImageXObj = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("resources/images/new.png", document);
            // Draw that image to the content stream
            pdPageContentStream.drawImage(pdImageXObj, 30, 650);
            pdPageContentStream.drawString();
            // Once all the content is written, close the stream
            pdPageContentStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: [The docs](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPageContentStream.html#drawString(java.lang.String)) suggest using `showText` instead.

Comment: Your IDE should have a shortcut to show the javadoc. In Netbeans, it is CTRL-SPACE.

Comment: @SuperStormer Thank you for the help, it worked..

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks for the information..

Comment: The "deprecated" message is not an error. Your code will run fine. It is just a warning nudging you to change your code because the method will be removed in the future.